# web design percent layout for ipad image height issue

Tags: html, ios, css, ipad, safari

I'm having problem with the sizing of images inside a definition list with percentage.
the page loads correctly in every browser that I tried on my desktop but for some reason on the iPad it bleeds the images outside of the DT tags.
I recreated this issue on jsbin for your comfort.
http://jsbin.com/okaqun/1

as you can see the database imgs are going out of the border lines.

Please help me solve this! it's been driving me crazy for too long!

Thank you!

Comment: no one knows the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution but it is not exactly what I wanted.
by setting the images with CSS as a background-image with image-size set to contain I got to the result I wanted on all the devices but it is far from optimal.

```
.list dt{
    background: #1B1B1B 0% no-repeat url('http://aux.iconpedia.net/uploads/21188781911187876141.png');
    background-size: contain;
    height: 17%;
    border-top: 1px solid #262626;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #101010;
}
```

Although by messing around with the code I think I've found something interesting...
if I set the DT height to 0% and then back to 17% the image inside resizes correctly.
any explanation for this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I believe iOS has problems scaling images that are uneven numbers (1, 3, 5, 7...). Have you tried changing the images to even widths/heights?